# This is how it keeps the token in local storage

Tags: angular, jwt, webapi

I want it to return token when I login in angular, but this way it returns token.

[image]

```
    return this.httpClient.post<LoginResponse>('/api/v1/login',
      loginRequestPayload).pipe(map(data => {
      this.localStorage.store("token", data.token);
      this.localStorage.store('success', data.success);
      this.localStorage.store('userId', data.userId);
```

i don't know what ngx-webstorage is.

I can't send token to backend while post process.

[image]

[image]

userId null!

intercept

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let newRequest : HttpRequest<any>;
    newRequest = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set("Authorization","Bearer " + token)
    })
    return next.handle(newRequest);
  }
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("ngx-webstorage|token")` should work, because the name of item is `ngx-webstorage|token` not just `token`

Comment: no, it didn't. `let token = localStorage.getItem("ngx-webstorage|token");`

Comment: If you just type `localStorage` in console's developer tools, it should print all storages, one of them should take your token @_@ https://prnt.sc/19s5hhe